# Uninstall a Component in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I installed [this](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) component in my application. I would like to uninstall it now. How can I do that ?

Comment: `uninstall` instead of `install` :v

Comment: which installation method did you use?